# Clojure, can not find an error in the code

Tags: clojure

```
(defn mapset [func ele]
  (loop [elements ele
         result []]
    (if (empty? elements)
     (set result)
     (let [[first-value & another] elements]
       (into result (func first-value))
       (recur another result)))))
(def v [1 2 3 4 5])
(mapset + v)
```

Exeption:

> Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long

Who knows how to fix it?

Comment: What is your goal? Are you trying to create your own implementation as an exercise or you want a function which returns a composition of map converting resulting seq into a set?

Comment: Yes, this is exercise in the book Clojure for brave.  
Also I just want to know what I did wrong, and why my code does not work

Comment: PS sorry for my English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first issue is that [`into`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into) accepts collections, not a collection and a single element. I think you wanted to use [`conj`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/conj) instead:

`(conj result (func first-value))`

Another issue is that Clojure collections (`result` vector in this case) are immutable thus functions like `conj` or `into` return a new updated collection instead of modifying their input parameters thus you need to use their result for `recur`:

```
(recur another (conj result (func first-value)))
```

And the last issue is that you are passing `+` function which when applied to a single argument will return it. I guess you wanted to use `inc` instead.

Thus your working code should look like:

```
(defn mapset [func ele]
  (loop [elements ele
         result []]
    (if (empty? elements)
      (set result)
      (let [[first-value & another] elements]
        (recur another (conj result (func first-value)))))))
(def v [1 2 3 4 5])
(mapset inc v)
;; => #{4 6 3 2 5}
```